# Timeago Jquery plugin not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeago

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/timeago.js" ></script>

$(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery("abbr.timeago").timeago();
});
```

html:

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="2008-07-17T09:24:17Z">July 17, 2008</abbr>
function Refresh() {
    setTimeout(function(){      
        <?php echo 'var id = '.json_encode($_GET['id']).';'; ?>
        $('#cmdz').load('cmdajax.php?id='+id);  
    },1000);
}
```

The `#cmdz` div contains the `abbr` tag. timeago working properly in onload but when the div is refreshed it won't works.

for some reason `jQuery("abbr.timeago").timeago();` function not working. Here you can find full code:[after ajax call jquery function not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11083768/after-ajax-call-jquery-function-not-working-properly)

Comment: link to jquery plug in : [link](http://timeago.yarp.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/FFeE3/1/

Can you please try sourcing your time ago.js from below link and any particular reason you are using `jQuery("abbr.timeago").timeago();` you can use `$("abbr.timeago").timeago();`

Hope this helps rest demo should give you more idea. cheers

**Script**

```
  <script type='text/javascript' src="https://github.com/petersendidit/jquery-timeago/raw/master/jquery.timeago.js"></script>
```

**code**

```
$("abbr.timeago").timeago();​
```

Comment: Thanks for the live timeago.js . But $("abbr.timeago").timeago();​
still not working . I think the abbr tag in a ajax response that may hurt my cod right?

Comment: Hiya, @Compiler code in ajax request? hmm are you adding the element dynamically? in that case you will trigger the Jquery when the htl is added. :) hope it helps cheers

Comment: added $("abbr.timeago").timeago(); to Refresh()  but still not working.

Answer (score 4):

Try out [Livestamp.js](http://mattbradley.github.com/livestampjs/). It's unobtrusive and auto-updating. All you need to provide is the Unix timestamp.

Comment: I could not get timeago to work on dynamically-created tags, even if I ran `$("abbr.timeago").timeago();` after every DOM insertion. It worked on the static elements, but ignored the dynamic ones. Livestamp worked just fine, including on dynamic elements.

Comment: Unfortunately, Livestamp.js (671 bytes) depends on Moment.js (15 kb). Would be nice to use Livestamp.js with native Javascript date objects, and avoid all that overhead. Regardless, thank you for creating Livestamp!

Answer (score 1):

Two way of representation, Do this way or other way but don't mix:-

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("abbr.timeago").timeago();
});
```

OR

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("abbr.timeago").timeago();
});
```